# Swapping two arrays using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

i I was wondering why code below doesn't work.  I have used pointer to copy array from one to another but it doesn't copy at all. Am I missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    char *pname;
    double points;
} STUD;

void stud_printx(STUD s) {
    printf("[%d:%s] = %lf\n", s.id, s.pname, s.points);
}

void stud_swap(STUD *s1, STUD *s2) { // space to be filled - my code written
STUD tmp;
     tmp = *s1;
     *s1 = *s2; 
     *s1 = tmp;    


}

int main(void) {
    STUD s1 = {1, "Choi", 9.9};
    STUD s2 = {2, "Park", 0.1};

    stud_printx(s1);
    stud_printx(s2);

    stud_swap(&s1, &s2 ); // space to be filled  - my code written 

    stud_printx(s1);
    stud_printx(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not every student is a stud :)

Comment: Re "*I have used pointer to copy array*", huh, there's no array in that program.

Comment: Voting to close as typo - it seems clear that you had `*s2 = tmp;` in mind but just didn't type it out right

Answer (score 2):

```
*s1 = *s2;  // Copy original *s2 into *s1
*s1 = tmp;  // Copy original *s1 into *s1
```

should be

```
*s1 = *s2;  // Copy original *s2 into *s1
*s2 = tmp;  // Copy original *s1 into *s2
```

Comment: I've looked over the code again and just noticed the mistake. Thank you!!